# How do i search post by jquery datepicker?

Tags: posts, filters, search, date

I'm working on the WordPress website I have my own search filter page, where I added the jquery datepicker, now I want to search post by datepicker?

**Html Code**

```
script>
$(function() {

   jQuery( "#datepicker-13" ).datepicker({
       dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd"
   });
   $("#datepicker-13").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
</script>

<input type = "text" name="datefrom" class="form-control alertform" id = "datepicker-13">
```

**Wordpress Query**

```
$datefrom = $_POST['datefrom'];

if(!empty($datefrom) && $datefrom !=='')
{
   $args    = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' =>8,
   'paged' => $paged,
   'post_date'  => $datefrom,
   'post_status' => 'publish' 
    );
}
 $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Here The Solution Of It

```
$datefrom = $_POST['datefrom'];
$time  = strtotime($datefrom);
$day   = date('d',$time);
$month = date('m',$time);
$year  = date('Y',$time);

$args = array(

    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' =>8,
    'paged' => $paged,

'date_query' => array(
    array(
   'year'  => $year,
   'month' => $month,
   'day'   => $day,
),
),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use date_query as argument, like so :

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'year=2012&monthnum=12&day=12' );

or:

$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => 2012,
            'month' => 12,
            'day'   => 12,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Source : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: i have tried your code but not working

Comment: If you can't get this to work, try using a prepared query like this :
        global $wpdb;
 $result = $wpdb->get_col( 
  $wpdb->prepare( "
   SELECT count(*) as number FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
   WHERE p.post_date = '%s'
   AND p.post_status = 'publish'",
   $your_date
  ) 
 );

Comment: im trying to using like this

`$orderdate = explode('-', $datefrom);
$month = $orderdate[0];
$day   = $orderdate[1];
$year  = $orderdate[2];
 
$args = array(

    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' =>8,
    'paged' => $paged,

  'date_query' => array(
    array(
      'year'  => $year,
      'month' => $month,
      'day'   => $day,
    ),
  ),
);`

Comment: humm, i see, you have to cast your vars to be integer instead of strings, like this :

$args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'post', 
  'posts_per_page' =>8, 
  'date_query' => array( 
   array( 
    'year' => (int)$year, 
    'month' => (int)$month, 
    'day' => (int)$day
   )
  )
 );